# I need user input to tell the program which list to use?

Tags: python

So i'm pretty new to python and i'm making a hangman program.  Here is the code I have so far.

```
import random
print('Welcome to hangman')
print('Type one of the following categories')
Animal=['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard']
Clothing=['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf']
Weather=['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Storms']
Colors=['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey']
print('Animal, Clothing, Weather, Colors')

category=input()
randomwordindex=random.randint(1,7)
```

Where it says `category=input()` I want the user input to be one of the lists I have above.  Then I can use `category` with an random integer to pick a random word to start the game.  How do I get the `input()` to be the list and not a string value?

Edit: Okay I got it thanks guys.

Here is the code that I have currently.  I'll probably add a for loop eventually and clean up my while loop so it's one line.

```
import random

print('Welcome to hangman')
print('Type one of the following categories')

Animal=['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard']
Clothing=['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf']
Weather=['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Stormy']
Colors=['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey']

print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')

category=int(input())

while category > 4:
    print('Your input isn\'t one of the categories. Make sure your choice is a number from 1 to 4.')
    print('Try entering again')
    print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')
    category=int(input())

while category == 0: 
    print('Your input isn\'t one of the categories. Make sure your choice is a number from 1 to 4.')
    print('Try entering again')
    print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')
    category=int(input())

if category == 1: secretword=random.choice(Animal)
if category == 2: secretword=random.choice(Clothing)
if category == 3: secretword=random.choice(Weather)
if category == 4: secretword=random.choice(Colors)
```

now the variable `secretword` stores the word that is randomly chosen from the list.

Comment: If your goal is for the user to input code, in this case a list, you can use the `eval()` function. It is very dangerous however, and should not be used in code other people will use. Using eval is basically transforming a string into real code. Can't you print the lists with a number, like `"Option 1. Animal"`? It seems more user friendly and safe.

Comment: @Mikael What is the difference between what I have and `"Option 1. Animal"`? Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python dictionary or you can add option and take option number from the user.

```
import random
print('Welcome to hangman')
print('Type one of the following categories')

Animal=['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard']
Clothing=['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf']
Weather=['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Storms']
Colors=['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey']

print('1.Press 1 for Animal, 2.Press 2 for Clothing')
print('3.Press 3 for Weather, 4.Press 4 for Colors')

category=int(input())

# you can iterate over this
if category == 1: random.choice(Animal)
elif category == 2: random.choice(Clothing)
elif category == 3: random.choice(Weather)
elif category == 4: random.choice(Colors)

randomwordindex = random.randint(1,7)
```

Comment: So when the code for `catagory=int(input())`, the code is assigning catagory an integer value based off what exactly in the input?  The user can just type a number that matches a category?  I guess what i'm asking is what integer is the `int(input())` finding? What does the `.Press` code do?

Comment: Okay I played with it a bit and figured out what I was asking in my first comment.  Just so people know if they read this in the future.  I was confused because I thought the user was still inputing Animal, But with the code above the user is entering a number.  The `.Press` means nothing it's just the way @Shaon shaonty decided to write the string.  The `.Press` does not assign anything to the number '1'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to map your lists to specific values. That way, you can accesses a category, programaticlly:

```
>>> categories = {
    'animal': ['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard'],
    'clothing': ['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf'],
    'weather': ['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Storms'],
    'colors': ['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey'],
    }
>>> 
>>> catagory = input()
animal
>>> categories[catagory]
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Cow', 'Fish', 'Lizard']
>>>
```

Also, you should use `random.choice()` instead to get a random element from the list:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice(categories[catagory])
'Fish'
>>>
```

Comment: Okay, I have been reading up on dictionaries and I think this is the cleanest way to go.  At this point i'm not that familiar with a lot of the imports and what their capabilities are.

Comment: I'll play around with it a bit

Answer (score 0):

Use the while block to validate the response.

```
valid_options = ['Animal', 'Clothing' , 'Weather', 'Colors' ]

while True:
    opt = input('Enter: ') 
    if opt in valid_options:
        break
    else:
        print('Not a valid option. Valid options are: %s', % ",".join(valid_options))
```

after this code, you can use Christian code to map the values of categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if given input string is a valid option else display valid options and wait till user enters one of the correct option or exit.

You can also display the keys by displaying from dictionary and not hard coding them.

```
import sys
import random

categories = {
    'animal': ['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard'],
    'clothing': ['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf'],
    'weather': ['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Storms'],
    'colors': ['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey'],
    'exit' : []
    }
keys = ""

print('Welcome to hangman')
print('Type one of the following categories')
for key, value in categories.items():
    keys = keys + key + " "
print(keys)
category = input()
while (True):
    if (category.isalpha() and (category.lower() in categories.keys())):
        if (category.lower() == 'exit'):
            print("Thanks for playing hangman!")
            sys.exit()
        print(categories[category.lower()])
        randomwordindex=random.randint(1,7)
        print(randomwordindex)
        ## TODO : play hangman, for now break to avoid infinite loop
        break
    else:
        print("valid options are: " + keys)
        category = input()
```

Sample Run

```
Welcome to hangman
Type one of the following categories
animal clothing weather colors exit 
anim
valid options are: animal clothing weather colors exit 
clo
valid options are: animal clothing weather colors exit 
1231
valid options are: animal clothing weather colors exit 
acsa12
valid options are: animal clothing weather colors exit 
animal
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Cow', 'Fish', 'Lizard']
7
>>> 

=============== RESTART ~/hangman.py ===============
Welcome to hangman
Type one of the following categories
animal clothing weather colors exit 
asn
valid options are: animal clothing weather colors exit 
1231
valid options are: animal clothing weather colors exit 
sadxasdn
valid options are: animal clothing weather colors exit 
exit
Thanks for playing hangman!
>>>
```